# PCA on groups of variables on same dataset

Tags: clustering, pca

Is it valid to perform a principal components analysis on different sets of variables for the same dataset? In the sample dataset I provide, can you take a PCA of parents_income, household_sz, financial_aid, and legacy in one analysis; GPA, SAT, and ACT in another; and the remaining in another?

[image: Sample Dataset]

It would effectively be 3 analyses for family background, test scores, and extra curricular activities.

Is there any statistical rule I am breaking by doing this?

Comment: What rule could you be possibly breaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly reasonable to preprocess different column groups independently.

There is no rule that says you must first stack columns then preprocess them; on the contrary, you are pretty much free to add and remove variables and process them independently. You still should be able to argue why you do this, though. Because preprocessing is pretty much arbitrary subjective choice anyway. Do you measure length in feet, or in meters? Human choice; neither is statistically more correct (U.S. metrics are stupid for various reasons, but not statistical validity as far as I can tell).

Now since PCA is a linear transform, applying PCA to column groups independently will **still yield a linear transform** overall; composed of blocks of the individual PCA runs, and 0s everywhere else. It doesn't get much more well-behaved than a linear transform.